# How to spawn object after 6 min in A-frame webvr?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am beginner to A-frame. so is there anyone who can help to solve this stuff,
I am stuck to spawn object after 6 second from starting of WebVR A-Frame in browser.

I can able to see the object in the browser but unable to set spawn time 6-second late from the start time of the WebVR.

Comment: Providing code and runnable example will make easier for people to help you,

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object in `js` with `document.createElement()`:

```
var box = document.createElement("a-box")
document.querySelector("a-scene").appendChild(box)
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/xgvfkhdo/2/).

---

For the 6 seconds bit, use `setTimeout(function() {}, ms)`. You can also add an event listener to the scene, listening when the scene was loaded, or when the renderer loop has started

```
scene.addEventListener("loaded", (e)=>{....
scene.addEventListener("renderstart", (e)=>{...
```

Docs on scene events [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/scene.html#events).